# In Dreaming Void (Commonwealth Saga) What happened to the SI

Tags: commonwealth-saga

Many of the original commonwealth characters from Pandora's Star appear or at least have a reference in the Dreaming Void.  The SI was the repository for many of the memories of people from the commonwealth in the Pandora's Star Era but this has been replaced by ANA.  What happened to the Machine Intelligence of the SI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rereading the series now and the SI do make a brief appearance in The Temporal Void, but there is little explanation as to where they have gone after ANA found them suspicious.

Comment: They didn't go anywhere, their planet was almost completely cut off from the unisphere after ANA started to distrust them.